# Bootstrap grid system half screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rows, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to make two rows with 4 each with 50% height of screen?

Bootstrap code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done if you're using Bootstrap 4..

```
.row {min-height: 100vh;}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/URV06dvkN0

For Bootstrap 3  (non flexbox) use this..

```
.row {height: 100vh;}
.row>.col-md-3 {height: 50%;}
```